# Parsing HTML tags to find a specific Table Row

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

Hello everyone I was set up with a Challenge where I must parse through an HTML page to find the end date of all the classes.  I am using the HTMLAgilityPack but, this is the first time I have used it, also the webpage who ever set it up has no classes or Id's and the end dates are stored in a Tr H4 tag.  I am not sure how to Parse through any hits?

My Code:

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.Load(txtURL.Text);

sw.WriteLine("GET /academics/academic-calendar/ HTTP/1.1");
sw.WriteLine();
String response = sr.ReadToEnd();

txtHTML.Text = response;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `HtmlDocument` object can be queried - you can use [XPath](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) to find all elements that follow a specific path or other constraint, you can also use LINQ to query.

I suggest downloading the source package - it comes with many projects with examples of usage.

Comment: Do you have the link to the direct-download on hand?

Comment: @moutonc - Really? This is a problem for you? http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/downloads/get/120937

Comment: Yeah Sorry, my Google skill, I forgot I had this is just what I needed to look at thank you! +1 + Answer

Answer (score 1):

Using XPath will allow you to get what you need.
Here is an example of how to get all the table rows from the declared html.

```
HtmlDocument htmlDocument = Markup.Parser();                                  
htmlDocument.LoadHtml(html);
htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("/tr");
```

Comment: nice one , shouldn't it be just that simple ??